# no module named "tensorflow.python.platform" when importing tensorflow || tflearn on python shell

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running python 3.7 on a windows 10 pc
i have been having trouble importing tensorflow or tflearn in my python project
every time after running

```
import tflearn 
import tensorflow
```

i always end up getting the same error

```
    import tflearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\genes\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\genes\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\genes\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform'
```

any idea on how to solve this for both tflearn && tensorflow import..

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: 
pip install tflearn

After this try importing tflearn again

Comment: I have tried several times it doesn't work on windows but works fine on ubuntu linux..

Comment: Could you share the errors that occur when you execute pip install tflearn?

Comment: Or you could also try updating pip and then install the package

Comment: I have tried that too, pip is int he latest version but still doesn't work am using python  3.7.3

Comment: the error is just the same as the one i attached on the questuib for both import tflearn and import tensorflow they return the same error that  no module named tensorflow.python.platform  the error seems to originate from this file 
`from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow ` on line 25

but i do not get any errors when installing the packages with pip they all install successifully